# Team Explorer Everywhere Command-Line - Minimum requirements

Tags: tfs, command-line-tool, team-explorer, team-explorer-everywhere

On a machine that contains Visual Studio 2010 installed (along with the Visual Studio Command Prompt + Team Foundation Client), I have developed a small bat file that contains TF commands in it.

Now I need to move it to our Windows Server 2012 and there is no Visual Studio installed in there. So I found this nice package: https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere

Out of it, I would like to make use of the "Command-Line Client" only. I have downloaded its package but I realized that, in order to make it work nicely, I suspect that I may need to install a few other components, such as Java.

It isn't clear what exactly are these components. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: We would encourage you not to use the TEE CLI (the cross-platform CLI) on Windows.  We would encourage you to install the Team Explorer 2017 standalone client: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/04/05/reintroducing-the-team-explorer-standalone-installer/

Comment: Thanks Edward. Problem is that our TFS version is 2010. Is it still feasible?

Comment: It seems TFS 2010 Service Pack 1, its Mainstream Support End Date on 14/07/2015

Answer (score 0):

From the Help folder that's part of the package:

> Operating system requirements:
>
> - Windows 10 (x86 and x64)
> - Windows 8.1 (x86 and x64)
> - Windows 8 (x86, x64)
> - Windows 7 (x86, x64)
> - Linux with GLIBC 2.3+ (x86, x86_64)
> - Mac OS X 10.8+ (Intel only)
>
> Java runtime requirements:
>
> - Oracle Java 1.7+ or IBM Java 1.7+ on Linux
> - Apple Java 1.7+ on Mac OS X
> - Oracle Java 1.7+ or IBM Java 1.7+ on Windows

Comment: Thanks, Jesse. I managed to get it working by installing Java only. Definitely worth compared to installing a bunch of Microsoft packages or even Visual Studio.